# Pandas: Dataframe to Panel error: NotImplementedError: Only 2-level MultiIndex are supported

Tags: python, pandas, ipython, panel

I am having trouble sending my data frame `to_Panel`. I'm performing preliminary operations on the data beforehand and am concerned that these may be contributing to the problem.

```
merge.head()

      date     catcode  type    di  cid     feccandid   amount  disposition     bills
0   2005-12-31  G1100   24K     D   N00004045   H2MI11042   1500    support     1
1   2005-12-31  L1100   24K     D   N00004045   H2MI11042   8000    support     1
2   2005-12-31  L1100   24K     D   N00004155   H2MI02066   1000    oppose  1
3   2005-12-31  T1200   24K     D   N00004166   H4MI03045   3000    support     1
```

Then I form a `pivot_table`

```
mm = merge.pivot_table(index=['date', 'feccandid', 'disposition', \
'bills', 'cid', 'di', 'type'], columns='catcode',values='amount', \
                       fill_value=0)

                                                            catcode     A0000   A1000   A1100   A1200   A1300   A1400   A1500   A1600   A2000   A2300   ...     T9100   T9400   X3700   X4000   X4100   X4110   X5000   X7000   Y0000   Z5200
date       feccandid    disposition     bills       cid     di  type                                                                                    
2005-12-31  H2MI02066   oppose             1    N00004155   D   24K     0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ...     0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
            H2MI11042   support            1    N00004045   D   24K     0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ...     0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
            H4MI03045   support            1    N00004166   D   24K     0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ...     0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0

3 rows × 315 columns
```

I then reset the index:

```
mm = mm.reset_index()
mm.head()

catcode     date    feccandid   disposition     bills   cid     di  type    A0000   A1000   A1100   ...     T9100   T9400   X3700   X4000   X4100   X4110   X5000   X7000   Y0000   Z5200
0        2005-12-31 H2MI02066     oppose        1   N00004155   D   24K     0   0   0   ...     0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
1        2005-12-31 H2MI11042     support       1   N00004045   D   24K     0   0   0   ...     0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
2        2005-12-31 H4MI03045     support       1   N00004166   D   24K     0   0   0   ...     0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

I then send to csv:

```
mm.to_csv('i.test', index=False)
```

Read from csv:

```
hh = pd.read_csv('i.test')
```

Set index:

```
hh.set_index(['date', 'feccandid']).head(3)
                    disposition    bills    cid     di     type     A0000   A1000   A1100   A1200   A1300   ...     T9100   T9400   X3700   X4000   X4100   X4110   X5000   X7000   Y0000   Z5200
date        feccandid                                                                                   
2005-12-31  H2MI02066   oppose        1   N00004155     D   24K     0   0   0   0   0   ...     0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
            H2MI11042   support       1   N00004045     D   24K     0   0   0   0   0   ...     0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
            H4MI03045   support       1   N00004166     D   24K     0   0   0   0   0   ...     0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

To panel:

```
hh.to_panel()

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NotImplementedError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-86-9358192e71a3> in <module>()
----> 1 hh.to_panel()

/home/jayaramdas/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in to_panel(self)
   1210         if (not isinstance(self.index, MultiIndex) or  # pragma: no cover
   1211                 len(self.index.levels) != 2):
-> 1212             raise NotImplementedError('Only 2-level MultiIndex are supported.')
   1213 
   1214         if not self.index.is_unique:

NotImplementedError: Only 2-level MultiIndex are supported.
```

Any ideas, question, or critiques?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`set_index` doesn't happen in place, so your `hh` doesn't have a MultiIndex as an index.

```
>>> hh.to_panel()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-4-9358192e71a3>", line 1, in <module>
    hh.to_panel()
  File "/home/dsm/sys/pys/3.5.1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 1224, in to_panel
    raise NotImplementedError('Only 2-level MultiIndex are supported.')
NotImplementedError: Only 2-level MultiIndex are supported.

>>> hh.set_index(["date", "feccandid"]).to_panel()
<class 'pandas.core.panel.Panel'>
Dimensions: 20 (items) x 1 (major_axis) x 3 (minor_axis)
Items axis: catcode to Z5200
Major_axis axis: 2005-12-31 to 2005-12-31
Minor_axis axis: H2MI02066 to H4MI03045
```

You could add `inplace=True` to the `set_index`, but it's considered slightly more pandorable to just do `hh = hh.set_index(...)` instead.

---

Aside: I think Panels are being gradually deprecated in favour of the richer `xarray` N-d object, so you might want to consider installing [`xarray`](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/) and then doing

```
>>> hh.to_xarray()
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:      (date: 1, feccandid: 3)
Coordinates:
  * date         (date) object '2005-12-31'
  * feccandid    (feccandid) object 'H2MI02066' 'H2MI11042' 'H4MI03045'
Data variables:
    catcode      (date, feccandid) int64 0 1 2
    disposition  (date, feccandid) object 'oppose' 'support' 'support'
    bills        (date, feccandid) int64 1 1 1
    cid          (date, feccandid) object 'N00004155' 'N00004045' 'N00004166'
    di           (date, feccandid) object 'D' 'D' 'D'
    type         (date, feccandid) object '24K' '24K' '24K'
    [...]
```

instead and experimenting that way.

Comment: Thank you so much! I should have (and do, but clearly spaced it) known that by now!